Userform scrollbar shifts down from the top when I click on a frame
I have a Userform, with a Multi-Page control that contains two frames on the first tab (this is the 'main' tab I reference 99% of the time).
When I open the Userform the scrollbar is at the top...perfect.
However, when I click on one of the frames the scrollbar shifts down to the top of the frame; hiding the header of the userform and the Multi-Page tabs.
Any tips on keeping the userform scrollbar at the top while working within the frames?
Thank you in advance!
